# reason: 'couldn't fork: errno 35' while importing video files ,converting and getting creation date

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, nstask

I am trying to import files from sdCard using sdcard reader on ipad. While importing the mts files from the card, i convert them to mov format and save it to the documents directory of the application. It completely converts the files if i dont call below mentioned function to get date. When i call this function to get creation date of the video file while importing. It crashes and gives the following stack trace....

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'couldn't fork: errno 35'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x32fba64f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35992c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x32fba491 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 68
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x32fba4cb +[NSException raise:format:] + 34
    4   Foundation                          0x3582be8f -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:] + 2138
    5   Foundation                          0x3582af57 -[NSConcreteTask launch] + 22
    6   IRVideoEditor                       0x0002f917 +[IRVideoManager getCreatedDate:] + 358
    7   IRVideoEditor                       0x0002f65d +[IRVideoManager duplicateExists:] + 240
    8   IRVideoEditor                       0x0002d6c9 -[IRVideoEncoder wrapVideos] + 752
    9   IRVideoEditor                       0x00016d27 -[ImportVideoViewController importVideo] + 170
    10  Foundation                          0x357b0389 -[NSThread main] + 44
    11  Foundation                          0x358225cd __NSThread__main__ + 972
    12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x36539311 _pthread_start + 248
    13  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x3653abbc start_wqthread + 0
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

bellow is the code, I am using to get date using nstask

NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];

```
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];


    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];


    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stat -c %%y %@", filePath], nil]; // iPad stat

    [task setArguments: arguments];

    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];

    [task setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]];
```

//        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(taskExited:) name:NSTaskDidTerminateNotification object:task];
        [task launch];
        //[task waitUntilExit];

```
    NSString * date = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
    return date;
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get `errno 1` "Operation not permitted".

Comment: any suggestions? trojanfoe

Comment: Yes; you cannot start processes under iOS and if all you want is file information I don't see why you would anyway.

Comment: We need creation time of the clips to resync them according to that time !! that information can be get while importing. So i need to get that time !! i am using nstask to get file size too and that is working fine